# SharedPreferences not saving boolean

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm having a strange issue with shared preferences on my Galaxy Note 3, The "saved_name" preference is working just fine, however when I try saving a boolean it doesn't save. In fact the Log reads:
before:true
after:false
This makes absolutly no sense.

```
   final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this); //Get the preferences
   final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
   auto_login_checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.e("login", "before: " + isChecked);
            editor.putBoolean("saved_login ", isChecked);
            editor.commit();

            boolean is_saved = prefs.getBoolean("saved_login", false);
            //WHY IS THIS PRINTING FALSE IF THE ABOVE IS TRUE?
            Log.e("saved", "after: " + is_saved);
        }
       });

   String name = prefs.getString("saved_name", null); //get a String
       if(name != null){
            usernameField.setText(name); 
          }
```

Comment: You have a trailing space after the first call to `putBoolean`. "saved_login" and "saved_login " are not the same thing.

Comment: That should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

remove the space from "saved_login" in the putBoolean like this :

```
editor.putBoolean("saved_login", isChecked);
```

Answer (score 1):

Omar's answer is correct.  Additionally, to avoid these sorts of issues in the future it's best practice to use static String variables to store the keys for your shared prefs

```
private static final String KEY_SAVED_LOGIN = "saved_login";
```

etc.